# Slow scroll when detect image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have the problem with the scenario.

1. We have a page with text which is scrollable
2. When image is detected, scrolling should be slower
3. When image is over, scrolling gets back to default speed.

I have detection of element and trying to do slowing scroll with using transform, but without luck. It is slower a little bit, but it does not look like properly.

```
function elementInViewport2(el) {
      var top = el.offsetTop;
      var left = el.offsetLeft;
      var width = el.offsetWidth;
      var height = el.offsetHeight;

      while(el.offsetParent) {
        el = el.offsetParent;
        top += el.offsetTop;
        left += el.offsetLeft;
      }

      return (
        top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
        left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
        (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
        (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
      );
    }

    /*window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
       var el = document.getElementById('slides');

       console.log(elementInViewport2(el));
    });*/

    $.fn.moveIt = function(){
      var $window = $(window);
      var instances = [];

      $(this).each(function(){
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
      });

      window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var el = document.getElementById('slides');

        if (elementInViewport2(el)) {
          instances.forEach(function(inst){
            inst.update(scrollTop, -20);
          });
        }
      }, {passive: true});
    }

    var moveItItem = function(el){
      this.el = $(el);
      console.log(el);
      this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
    };

    moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop, speed){
      this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / speed) + 'px)');
    };

    // Initialization
    $(function(){
      $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pnrszyzn/

Comment: How about using the css only [parallax scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/tour-performant-responsive-css-site/) effect?

Comment: I tested, in many cases is fine for scrolling background and text layer in different speed, but it this scenario is a little bit different.

Comment: Modifying scroll speed isn't possible, as that's something defined by system and/or browser settings for the end-user. You do have some power in affecting inertia for mousewheels and probably touch swipes, however the standard scrolling (up/down arrow) is an on/off action (precise) and moves a set number of lines within the page (as configured in the system or browser).

Comment: Perhaps look at counter-acting the users scrolling, for example, if they scrolled 300px, you reverse 1/3 (to 100px) so they've made less scrolling progress than normal. However it's doubtful this will ever look good or be enjoyable. Or look at dynamically adjusting the top and bottom margins of the entire page to counter-act scroll position while the element is in view, however I know from experience you'll be fighting with 'elastic' scrolling on iOS.